# Распарсить список

Tags: javascript, массивы, list

Доброго времени суток!

Есть список в таком виде (его возвращает питон):

```
var arr = ['1234:2','1234:3', '1234:4', '1234:5' ]
```

Я его принимаю и нужно в html вывести данный список в таблице.

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Ключ</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Что значит табличку? В каком виде табличку? Какая структура данных в итоге должна получиться? Не понятно. Опиши задачу более полно.

Comment: @alex-sazonov , спасибо, дополнил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если обязательно в цикле, можно так:

```js
const arr = ['1234:2','1234:3', '1234:4', '1234:5'];

for (const string of arr) {
  const [first, second] = string.split(':');
  console.log(`${first} | ${second}`); // Тут можно составлять таблицу шаг за шагом.
}
```

Comment: Вот! Это хороший пример с деструктуризацией :) Дякую ;)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так я вижу заполнение.

```js
var arr = ['1234:2','1234:3', '1234:4', '1234:5' ];

const tr = [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')].splice(1);

tr.forEach((row, index) => {
  const [ID, KEY] = row.children;
  ID.textContent = arr[index].split(':')[0];
  KEY.textContent = arr[index].split(':')[1];
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Ключ</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ['1234:2','1234:3', '1234:4', '1234:5']
console.log(arr.map(x => x.split(':')))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```